# Qual a diferença entre usar propriedade virtual ou não no EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, orientação-a-objetos, entity-framework-6

Tenho meus models

```
public class Cliente
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string Nome {get;set;}
}
```

e

```
public class Pedido
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public int ClienteId {get;set;}
   public virtual Cliente Cliente {get;set;}
}
```

Seguindo o exemplo acima, qual é a diferença entre

```
public virtual Cliente Cliente {get;set;}
```

e

```
public Cliente Cliente {get;set;}
```

Sempre reparo que ao usar `virtual` o meu model Cliente vem carregado

por ex:

```
var pedido = dbo.Pedidos.Find(1);
```

Se eu tentar acessar `pedido.Cliente` ele não é `null` quando se está `virtual`

Qual é a diferença? Como o `EF` faz a `query` ? Qual forma tenho mais performance?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Lazy Loading

> [Lazy Loading](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lazy_loading) é o mecanismo utilizado pelos frameworks de persistência
>   para carregar informações sobre demanda. Esse mecanismo torna as
>   entidades mais leves, pois suas associações são carregadas apenas no
>   momento em que o método que disponibiliza o dado associativo é
>   chamado. Assim quando objetos são retornados por uma consulta, os
>   objetos relacionados não são carregados ao mesmo tempo, ao invés, eles
>   são carregados automaticamente quando a propriedade de navegação for
>   acessada.

O modificador `virtual` é utilizado pelo EF para fazer o *Lazy Loading*, que precisa criar instâncias de proxy que serão substituídas nessas propriedades virtuais.

Por isso você tem a impressão de que esse objeto está sempre carregado. Mas de fato ele não está. Uma propriedade virtual só é carregado via *lazy loading* no momento em que há a primeira referência a essa propriedade. Nesse momento o EF executa uma nova consulta na base de dados solicitando apenas os dados abaixo da hierarquia do objeto dessa propriedade.

Isso pode ser percebido ao debugar seu código no Visual Studio, a propriedade `virtual` será carregada no exato momento em que você verificar o seu valor.

O uso de *Lazy Loading* pode sim trazer problemas de performance. No seu exemplo, se fizer uma consulta que retorna, digamos, 100 `Pedidos`, sem carregar os clientes explicitamente *(eager loading)*, ao referenciar qualquer informação de `Cliente`, pra cada cliente diferente, será feita uma nova consulta na base de dados. Portanto nesse caso você poderia ter 100 novas consultas ao banco de dados.

```
var pedidos = db.Pedidos.ToList(); // não traz nenhuma informação de cliente
foreach (var pedido in pedidos) 
{
    var nome = pedido.Cliente.Nome; // aqui é feita a carga por Lazy Loading
}
```

### Eager Loading

Pra evitar esse efeito é possível informar que você deseja que o EF faça *Eager Loading* dos clientes usando uma cláusula `Include`.

```
var pedidos = db.Pedidos.Include(m => m.Cliente).ToList(); // inclui cliente na query
foreach (var pedido in pedidos) 
{
    var nome = pedido.Cliente.Nome; // os dados de cliente já estão carregados
}
```

Dessa forma a query SQL irá incluir os clientes na consulta.

Nos casos em que não usamos o modificador `virtual` só poderemos acessar o `Cliente` por *Eager Loading*.

O EF usa *Lazy Loading* por default em propriedades marcadas com o modificador `virtual`, caso contrário ele é desligado e por isso a referência ao objeto é `null` (exceto quando usamos *eager loading* através de `Include`).

É possível configurar o EF pra que não trabalhe com *Lazy Loading* mesmo quando temos propriedades virtuais.

```
public class MeuContexto : DbContext 
{ 
    public MeuContexto () 
    { 
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: todas as respostas foram ótimas e esclarecedoras, entretanto a sua passa uma explicação fácil e com exemplos, por isso a escolha da melhor, obrigado @iuristona

Answer (score 13):

Concordo com a [resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/52910/2998),e tenho alguns ponto a acrescentar.

Apesar de não trabalhar efetivamente com **EF**, sei que ele assim como o **NHibernate** (ORM similar ao EF), cria uma classe derivada denominada *proxy*, tendo como principal intuito a criação de gatilhos para os `getters` e `setters` na sua entidade, assim o ORM pode controlar, quanto, como e se um atributo/propriedade de sua entidade persistente foi alterada, para poder tomar as devidas ações em relação a isso.

Assim se você não deixa um atributo `virtual`, você está explicitamente dizendo que o mesmo não pode ser sobrescrito (*override*) em uma classe derivada a sua, sendo assim o ORM não conseguira implementar um *proxy* para este atributo/propriedade, não podendo consequentemente implementar os gatilhos.

> Obs: com NHibernate é obrigatório a utilização do modificador virtual em todas as propriedades mapeadas ao ORM, se isso não ocorrer um erro é gerado no momento da criação das configurações do mesmo. Sendo assim ele necessita a criação de *proxis* para sua utilização, já o EF, não necessitada explicitamente do virtual (dai, já não entendo como ele faz, uma possível explicação talvez seja o [comentário de @Tobias Mesquita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52908/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-usar-propriedade-virtual-ou-n%C3%A3o-no-ef/52934#comment108461_52934)).

Comment: No caso do EF estes gatilhos são necessarios para fazer o lazy load eo tracking das entidades, caso opte por desativar o tracking e passe a consultar os relacionamentos manualmente ou atraves de eager load, não é necessario manter o virtual.

Comment: gatinhos oO kkk

Comment: @Rod, nossa nem tinha visto, kkkkkk. Erro meu, faltei algumas aulas de português, irei corrigir. Tava pensando em gatinhos eu acho, quando estava escrevendo. Hehe.

Comment: @Rod, nossa e coloquei 2 vezes. kkkkk. Faltou mais algum? Hehe.

Answer (score 12):

Ele cria uma classe derivada da sua classe para trabalhar internamente. Este é um padrão chamado *dynamic proxy*. Isto facilita a navegação nos dados.

## Polimorfismo

Como a classe é derivada a chamada precisa ser feita no método `get` da propriedade da classe derivada que terá a lógica efetiva de carga do dado. Sem o `virtual` não há [polimorfismo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfismo) e o método chamado é o da sua classe `Pedido` que não contém nenhuma lógica de carga de dados, portanto é coerente ter `null` neste caso.

O `virtual` é usado justamente para criar uma indireção, assim o método a ser chamado não é chamado de forma direta, mas sim através de uma tabela que indicará qual é o método correto a ser chamado na hierarquia de classes de acordo com o dado concreto que está sendo manipulado.

Se você chama um método que não foi definido como `virtual`, a chamada é feita de forma direta e fixa, ou seja, se o método a ser chamado é o `get Cliente` da classe `Pedido`, é sempre ele mesmo que será chamado e não haverá uma forma de chamar o `get Cliente` de uma classe derivada mesmo que o objeto seja do tipo da classe derivada.

## Conclusão

A execução da *query* será responsabilidade do `get Cliente` existente na classe interna do EF derivada da sua classe `Pedido`. A carga do dado ocorre sob demanda, o chamado [*lazy loading*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading), e sem o `virtual` a carga deverá feita manualmente, talvez na sua classe `Pedido` na forma imediata *eager loading*. A *query* é montada com alguma forma de LINQ (veja comentário abaixo do TobyMosque).

A performance de cada um depende de como você vai usar. Em muitos casos a "carga preguiçosa" pode economizar processamento, mas em alguns padrões de acesso isto pode se voltar contra você.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: está mais do que correto, no caso do EF, o objeto sabe à qual contexto ele pertence e o contexto conhece os Mapeamentos, no caso acima a propriedade `Cliente` irá executar `context.Clientes.Find(this.ClienteId)`, assim como uma propriedade `Pedidos` em Clientes (se adicionada ao modelo acima) irá ser traduzida como `context.Pedidos.Where(pedido => pedido.ClienteId == this.Id)`