# Herança correta no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orientação-a-objetos, herança

Tenho uma classe mãe `DadosClientes` e duas classes filhas `DadosClientesPF`, e `DadosClientesPJ`.

A instancia `DadosCliente` tem o campo: `Nome`, `Telefone`

A instancia `DadosClientePF` tem o campo: `CPF`

A instancia `DadosClientePJ` tem o campo: `CNPJ`

O objeto cliente tem uma instancia `DadosClientes`, porem ele só acessa os campos do `DadosCliente`, como faço para acessar os campos `CPF` e `CNPJ`?

Comment: Poderia fornecer o código para que possamos te ajudar de maneira mais precisa?

Suponho que você esta utilizando herança para compor Cliente, DadosClientes, DadosClientesPF e DadosClientesPJ certo?

Comment: Criando uma instância de `DadosClientesPF` ou `DadosClientesPJ`. Você não pode acessar o que não existe. Se o problema não for só isto, explique melhor e coloque algum exemplo.

Comment: @KleberBarros, como o bigown apontou, não acho uma boa ideia ficar fazendo box e unbox de `DadosClientePF` e `DadosClientePJ`. Em todo caso te aconselho uma leitura complementar quanto aos modelos de herança no EF: Table-per-Type (TPT), Table-per-Hierarchy(TPH) e Table-per-Concrete(TPC).
http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

Comment: @TobyMosque Box e unbox é uma terminologia usada para value-types. Provavelmente você estava se referindo a type-casts entre classes base e derivadas.

Comment: Falha minha, obrigado pela correção.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Se você quer pegar uma propriedade, você tem que instanciar uma classe que tenha esta propriedade. Então se quer o `CPF`, precisa instanciar a `DadosCLientesPF`. Se instanciar a `DadosClientes` não tem como pegar o CPF simplesmente porque ele não existe neste classe.

Se você está usando um método que recebe `DadosClientes` e precisa acessar algo que não está disponível nele, está fazendo algo errado também. Neste caso o correto seria ter métodos separados para lidar com `DadosClientesPF`, com `DadosCLientesPJ` e talvez até manter o que lida só com o `DadosClientes` se for útil, o que eu duvido.

Especialmente no gosto da solução dada na outra resposta. Eu não sou purista mas aquilo não é programação orientada a objeto. Os métodos não devem ter que saber lidar com objetos derivados do tipo tipo esperado. Quando isto é necessário, métodos especializados devem ser criados, caso contrário, se depois for criado `ClientesDadosEstrangeiro` teria que mexer na implementação deste método. Dependendo do cenário pode não ser problemático mas em outros pode ser. Não não sei se precisa usar herança neste caso, mas se vai usar, faça pelos motivos certos, e use ela do jeito certo.

Se você separou em duas classes, trate-os como coisas diferentes. Se a intenção é tratar como se fosse a mesma coisa, não separe.

Mas se o seu problema for de polimorfismo (não que seja o caso), ou seja, você está instanciando a classe derivada mas quando passa ela para algum método que espera a classe base, aí seu problema é que a [propriedade precisa ser virtual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52908/101). Isto garante o polimorfismo e vai chamar a propriedade corretamente, já que ela interpretará o objeto com seu tipo originalmente instanciado e não pelo tipo concretamente declarado no parâmetro do método. Evidentemente isto só vale se a propriedade existe na classe base.

Talvez você precise [reavaliar toda sua modelagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14839/101).

Answer (score 4):

Após carregar o objeto `cliente` do BD,
você poderá verificar o tipo da propriedade.

Exemplo usando o operador `as`:

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    var cli = context.Clientes.Where(c => c.Id == idCli).Single();
    var pf = cli.DadosClientes as DadosClientePF;
    if (pf != null)
    {
        // pessoa física
        var cpf = pf.CPF;
    }

    var pj = cli.DadosClientes as DadosClientePJ;
    if (pj != null)
    {
        // pessoa jurídica
        var cnpj = pj.CNPJ;
    }
}
```

Para criar um novo cliente, basta criar uma das classes `DadosClientePF` ou `DadosClientePJ` e atribuir à propriedade `cli.DadosClientes`:

```
using (var context = new Context())
{
    var cli = new Cliente();
    if (cnpj != null)
    {
        cli.DadosClientes = new DadosClientePJ
            {
                CNPJ = cnpj
            };
    }

    if (cpf != null)
    {
        cli.DadosClientes = new DadosClientePF
            {
                CPF = cpf
            };
    }

    if (cli.DadosClientes != null)
        cli.DadosClientes.Nome = nome;

    context.Clientes.Add(cli);
    context .SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que você tenha:

```
class DadosCliente
{
  public string Nome { get; set; }
  public string Telefone { get; set; }
}

class DadosClientePF : DadosCliente
{
  public string CPF { get; set; }
}

class DadosClientePJ : DadosCliente
{
  public string CNPJ { get; set; }
}
```

E instancia um objeto PF:

```
DadosClientePF obj = new DadosClientePF{
  Nome = 'Nome',
  CPF = '000.000.000-00'
};
```

E então executa um método que recebe um parâmetro do tipo DadosCliente:

```
void Testar(DadosCliente dados)
```

Para acessar as propriedades das classes filho neste método você precisa checar o tipo da instância e fazer um cast:

```
if (dados is DadosClientePJ)
{
    DadosClientePJ dadosPj = (DadosClientePJ)dados;
    Console.Write(dadosPj.CNPJ);
}
else if (dados is DadosClientePF)
{
    DadosClientePF dadosPf = (DadosClientePF)dados;
    Console.Write(dadosPf.CPF);
}
```