# Método que funciona sem eu chamá-lo diretamente

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, entity-framework

Estou mexendo com o Entity Framework e estava fazendo mapeamento para uma classe Many to Many.

O que acontece é que usei um método que posso utilizar dentro da `DbContext` para renomear uma tabela, e ele funciona sem problemas.

Mas fiquei me perguntando como esse método funciona sendo que eu não chamo ele em nenhum lugar do meu programa? No caso seria o método `OnModelCreating()`.

```
class EfContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Editora> EditorasDbSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cliente> ClientesDbSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Estado> EstadosDbSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Governador> GovernadorsDbSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Departamento> DepartamentosDbSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Funcionario> FuncionariosDbSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pedido> PedidosDbSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Consumidor> ConsumidoresDbSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Autor> AutorsDbSet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Livro> LivrosDbSet { get; set; }

    public EfContext()
    {
        CustomDBInitializer initializer = new CustomDBInitializer();
        Database.SetInitializer<EfContext>(initializer);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Autor>().HasMany(autor => autor.Livros).WithMany(livro => livro.Autores).Map( x => 
        {
            x.ToTable("livros_e_autores");
            x.MapLeftKey("autor_id");
            x.MapRightKey("livro_id");
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Comment: Acredito que você tenha mais curiosidade na forma em que esse processo é implementadoe executado. Você pode conferir o projeto do EF Core que tem o código aberto diretamente no github ou então utilizar alguma ferramenta de decompiler dll para ver o próprio código da versão que você está utilizando. Segue a referência do dotPeek da Jetbrains que é uma ferramenta bastante conhecida para realizar esse procedimento: https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/. LA.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro você precisa entender [o que é um *framework*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101).

Você está herdando de [`DbContext`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext?view=entity-framework-6.2.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que o Entity Framework sabe o que é e sabe que existe um método `OnModelCreating()`. Em algum lugar dentro de toda infraestrutura do EF este método é chamado quando é adequado. Ele sabe quando precisa dele.

O que ele deixa você fazer é escrever a implementação desse método na sua classe classe herdada, por isso ele estabelece o [`virtual`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/151243/101) e você o faz com `override`.

Então quando você passar um objeto `EfContext` em um lugar que espera um `DbContext`, afinal eles são compatíveis, e isto é [polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153042/101), ele chamará o seu método e não o método do `DbContext`. Ele sabe o que chamar, mas não sabe o que será executado, você define isto. Inteligente, não?

Um exemplo diferente disso pode ser visto em [Qual a diferença entre usar propriedade virtual ou não no EF?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52908/101).

Comment: Valeu pela resposta Maniero, mas eu queria saber mesmo é como o Entity Framework faz isso.  Vou tentar dar um exemplo pra ver se consigo explicar onde realmente está minha dúvida. Por exemplo, se eu criar uma classe própria, quando eu instancia-la nada será executado a não ser que eu tenha algo no meu construtor, se eu quiser chamar um método dessa classe eu tenho que chama-lo através da instancia. Nesse caso do EfContext no construtor eu tenho o Database.SetInitializer. Eu imaginei que poderia ser através desse método que isso aconteceria?

Comment: Já deu uma olhada no código-fonte (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6)?