# Dúvida com propriedades virtuais

Tags: c#

Tenho duas tabelas: `A` e `B`

Na tabela `A` tenho:

```
Id
Nome
```

Na tabela `B` tenho:

```
Id
Nome
IdA(FK) -> de A
```

Na aplicação seria isso?

```
public class A
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Nome { get; set; }
  public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
```

e em `B` eu faria

```
public class B
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Nome { get; set; }
  public int? IdA { get; set; }
  public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

É isso ou oposto? Só para entender sobre propriedades virtuais

Answer (score 3):

Marcar uma propriedade como virtual indica que ela pode ser sobrescrita por classes filhas. Alguns frameworks como o `EntityFramework` utilizam as propriedades virtuais para criar `Proxies`, permitindo a implementação de `lazy loading`.

Também no caso do EntityFramework, as `Navigation Property` precisam ser marcadas como virtual se você deseja habilitar o `Lazy Loading`.

[Na resposta dessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52908/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-usar-propriedade-virtual-ou-n%C3%A3o-no-ef) há mais detalhes sobre propriedades virtuais e lazy loading.